# In one activity need to display 3 bottom sheets

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

we are trying to achieve a UI design which is similar to the UI shown in this below video:

[Video to demonstrate required UI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-ch0Q5Ycql5cM8kKIC5e9_WJP_dhGOCp/view?usp=sharing)

If anyone has any idea on how to implement this UI, please guide me.

Im new to Android Development, If more information required I'll provide.

Comment: That's probably a Custom Sectioned Recycler View not a bottom sheet..

Comment: that's not a bottom sheet

Comment: @ADM I'm  concerned about the top 4cards(all about this place, order food online etc..) behaviour as we scroll up they are stacking up behind each other and as we scroll down they are coming to normal position

Comment: @Sagargujarati please suggest how can I achieve that functionality

Answer (score 0):

You should implement design elements such as RecyclerView, CardView within your gradle and modify them as you like in the XML.

I leave you an example video of UI design in Android Studio that you can follow to achieve what you want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeQ1XHgQxHw

Comment: this solution is completely unrelated to my problem statement if possible please suggest me a better way